# Any way to Export WA conversation and convert .json to a flow diagram (similar to Visio)?

Tags: json, watson-assistant

Is there a way to export WA conversations (automatically exporting to .json file) and have converted to a Visio, or similar, type diagram showing actual flows?

Answer (score 0):

You can export a dialog skill / workspace either through [the browser UI](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-backup) or the [API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1?code=node#get-information-about-a-workspace). Another option is through 3rd party tools like [my conversation tool](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/).

I don't know of any conversion tool from the dialog nodes in the JSON files to something like Visio. There are cross links from the individual dialog nodes to parents and children which you would need to analyze.